# Calling a webhook inside a handler

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

is there any way to customize the answer coming from a handler (in a slot node in a dialog).
For example, in a table reservation app, when the assistant asks "What day you want to book a table?", i would like to provide a set of dynamic options, to answer user's questions like "when is the earliest available?" with options from a db, for instance.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You mean that the user has a predefined set of inputs? The Bot asks "What day" and the user has a selection for example Mo, Thu, Wed to pick from?

Comment: not exactly, but the opposite, you don't know before hand what day are available, the list is coming from a webhook :)

Comment: But that is exactly what is explained here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-webhooks. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Well, not exactly, if you read that document (or this https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-tutorial-slots) you'll find there are "handlers" for answers not covered by your multiple slots, like in my initial example.
My question is if you can call webhooks somehow in those handlers, but i'm starting to suspect you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

As of January of 2021, you cannot call a webhook inside a handler